# Table data are not shown in the depended field - BreezingForms - Mariadb

Tags: joomla-3.x, database

I have  2 set of fields: Set A (Field1, Field2), and Set B (Field3, Field4).

- Field1 loads data from Mariadb tableA according to user selection and then loads the corresponding data from tableA to Field2. In order for this to happen, a .php file named 1-2.php is used. Field1 and Field2 work ok but:

**Issue for Set A**: Inspect Element->Console in the Front End shows all data of the Field2.

- Field3 loads data from Mariadb tableB according to user selection and then loads the corresponding data from tableB to Field4. In order for this to happen, a .php file named 3-4.php is used. Field3 loads ok from tableB but:

**Issue for Set B**: Field4 shows nothing!

*Note tableA and tableB structure is identical

***1. Set A (Field1 and Field2)***

**Field1->Actionscript->Custom->Change:**

```
function ff_field1_action(element, action)
{
    switch (action) {
        case 'change':
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://someurl/1-2.php",
                data: { field1: element.value },    
                success: function(data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                        jQuery('#ff_elem2496').empty();
                       var arr = obj;
                           jQuery('#ff_elem2496').append(jQuery('<option>', {
                                value: '',
                                text: 'whatever'
                            }));
                       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
                           console.log(arr[i]);
                           jQuery('#ff_elem2496').append(jQuery('<option>', {
                                value: arr[i],
                                text: arr[i]
                            })); 
                        }
                }      
            });
            break;
        default:;
    } // switch
} // ff_field1_action
```

Note: elem2496 refers to Field2

**1-2.php file for Set A:**

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1);
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}
if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
$judgePick1 = JRequest::getVar(field1);
$db1 = JFactory::getDbo();
$query1 = $db1->getQuery(true);
$query1
  ->select('x.name')
  ->from($db1->quoteName('#__tableA', 'x'))
  ->join('LEFT', $db1->quoteName('#__tableA', 'y') . ' ON ' . $db1->quoteName('x.parent') .' = '. $db1->quoteName('y.id'))
  ->where($db1->quoteName('y.name') .' = '. $db1->quote($judgePick1))
  ->andWhere(array($db1->quoteName('x.parent').' = '. $db1->quoteName('y.id'), $db1->quoteName('x.active').' = 1'), $glue = 'AND')
  ->order($db1->quoteName('x.name') . ' ASC');
$db1->setQuery($query1);
$result1 = $db1->loadColumn();
 if(!$result1){
    echo "error";
} else {
    echo json_encode($result1);
}
?>
```

***2. Set B (Field3 and Field4)***

**Field3->Actionscript->Custom->Change:**

```
function ff_field3_action(element, action)
{
    switch (action) {
        case 'change':
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://someurl/3-4.php",
                data: { field3: element.value },    
                success: function(data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                        jQuery('#ff_elem3871').empty();
                       var arr = obj;
                           jQuery('#ff_elem3871').append(jQuery('<option>', {
                                value: '',
                                text: 'whatever2'
                            }));
                       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
                           console.log(arr[i]);
                           jQuery('#ff_elem3871').append(jQuery('<option>', {
                                value: arr[i],
                                text: arr[i]
                            })); 
                        }
                }      
            });
            break;
        default:;
    } // switch
} // ff_field3_action
```

Note: elem3871 refers to Field4

**3-4.php file for Set B:**

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1);
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}
if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
$judgePick2 = JRequest::getVar(field3);
$db2 = JFactory::getDbo();
$query2 = $db2->getQuery(true);
$query2
  ->select('x.name')
  ->from($db2->quoteName('#__tableB', 'x'))
  ->join('LEFT', $db2->quoteName('#__tableB', 'y') . ' ON ' . $db2->quoteName('x.parent') .' = '. $db2->quoteName('y.id'))
  ->where($db2->quoteName('y.name') .' = '. $db2->quote($judgePick2))
  ->andWhere(array($db2->quoteName('x.parent').' = '. $db2->quoteName('y.id'), $db2->quoteName('x.active').' = 1'), $glue = 'AND')
  ->order($db2->quoteName('x.name') . ' ASC');
$db2->setQuery($query2);
$result2 = $db2->loadColumn();
if(!$result2){
    echo "error";
} else {
    echo json_encode($result2);
}
?>
```

**Finally, in Form->Advanced->More Options->Form Pieces->Before Form:**

```
// Set A 
$this->execPieceByName('ff_InitLib'); //Include BreezingForms Library
$db1 = JFactory::getDBO();//Get Database Object
$db1->setQuery('SELECT name FROM #__tableA WHERE parent=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY id ASC');
$result1 = $db1->loadColumn(); //load the result from the query
$res1 = "0;whatever;0\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result1); $i++)
{
     $res1 .= "0;".$result1[$i].";".$result1[$i]."\n";
}
 function ff_setSelectList1($name, $value)
{
     global $ff_processor;
     for ($r = 0; $r < $ff_processor->rowcount; $r++)
     {
          $row =& $ff_processor->rows[$r];
          if ($row->name==$name)
          $row->data2 = $value;
          unset($row);
     } // for
} // ff_setSelectList1
 ff_setSelectList1('field1', $res1);

// Set B 
$this->execPieceByName('ff_InitLib'); //Include BreezingForms Library
$db2 = JFactory::getDBO();//Get Database Object
$db2->setQuery('SELECT name FROM #__tableB WHERE parent=0 AND active=1 ORDER BY id ASC');
$result2 = $db2->loadColumn(); //load the result from the query
$res2 = "0;whatever2;0\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result2); $i++)
{
     $res2 .= "0;".$result2[$i].";".$result2[$i]."\n";
}
function ff_setSelectList2($name, $value)
{
     global $ff_processor;
     for ($r = 0; $r < $ff_processor->rowcount; $r++)
     {
          $row =& $ff_processor->rows[$r];
          if ($row->name==$name)
          $row->data2 = $value;
          unset($row);
     } // for
} // ff_setSelectList2
ff_setSelectList2('field3', $res2);
```

**The structure of Table A and Table B is the following:**

```
Id  parent  name        uri         active
1   0       greekname1  latinname1  1
2   0       greekname2  latinname2  1
3   0       greekname3  latinname3  1
4   1       greekname4  latinname4  1
5   1       greekname5  latinname5  1
6   2       greekname6  latinname6  1
7   3       greekname7  latinname7  1
```

Comment: @mickmackusa First of all, thanks for having a look at it. The part that you mention is exactly as suggested by BreezingForms website and forum. I tried contacting Crosstec before postng here but sadly I was informed that they are facing a covid19 issue. Therefore, I was trying to figure out the proper syntax myself for "// Set B" as this looks to me to be the cause of the "Issue for Set B", but didn't work good so far. As for the "Issue for Set A" I tried removing "// Set B" but it went on appearing. So it must be irrelevant. Thanks

Comment: I may need to ask for proof that this is a coding problem versus a data problem.  Are you able to definitively rule out the notion that there is simply no qualifying data in table 4 that relates to the selection in table 3?  Please see this recent post which offers diagnostic techniques: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/27909/12352  this may uncover some new clues.

Comment: I thought I found the fatal typos.  Look at `JRequest::getVar(field1);` and `JRequest::getVar(field3);`  these attempts to grab submitted values are using an undefined CONSTANT called `field#`, but you want to access the values relating to the string keys, so you must wrap those words in single or double quotes.  Actually, these are not fatal, they will merely generate warnings. https://3v4l.org/QgJ0L so this is not a resolving fix.  I'm afraid I am going to need to know the incoming value and your database schema.

Comment: The 2 tables have identical structure. Therefore, why table A works fine for Field Set A and table B doesn’t for Field Set B?
The Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, are the names of the fields. I have used Field1, Field2, etc as an example for JSE. Maybe I should have used Fieldname1, Fieldname2, etc. Field Set B loads data from the table B only to Field3, and when you select an option, nothing appears to Field4. This doesn’t happen in case of Set Fields A where Field1 loads data from table A and when you make your selection Field2 brings the corresponding data from the table. Structure posted.

Comment: So the structures are identical, but the values differ, so we need to review the actual data.  Are you printong the judgepicks to screen? Did you run my recommended diagnostics?

Comment: I will do so a bit later and will let you know later on today. Thanks mickmackusa

Comment: @mickmackusa Running diagnostic didn't produce any result to me (unless I did something wrong).

Comment: The dignostic was run in **3-4.php** file for Set B

Comment: After work (if I have time) I will copy your snippets, inject a bunch of diagnostic techniques and send the updated snippets back to you to run in your project.  I want to see everything -- incoming variables, rendered queries, results sets, return values ...everything.   Gotta keep hunting for clues until we find some relevant ones.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: This entirely untested. https://3v4l.org/Iha1H  I have added a bunch of checkpoints; if I have missed any, feel free to add more checks.  Please check your error logs and turn Joomla's error reporting to the highest level while running diagnostics.  If there are typos or errors in my script, try to resolve them yourself, otherwise you will need to be very articulate about where my advice is breaking down.  With any luck, we will discover new clues as to why your script is breaking.  Until I hear back from you, I'll cross my fingers.

Comment: Any joy, @Gal??

Comment: @mickmackusa As I had to recover from a PC disaster, will start working on this tonight. Thank you for the suggestions, I will be back soon hopefully with good news!

Comment: Back to this issue after quite some time due to some unfortunate circumstances...! I have changed `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` in filed3,  to `var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));` and now it shows the `text: 'whatever2' `. But that's all... I will search more following @mickmackusa instructions and come back again.

Comment: Continuing... The text: `whatever2` appears in field4 but when I click on the list it shows the word `error` in vertical (letter by letter)

Comment: I am just re-acquainting myself with your question. `, $glue = 'AND'` can be removed.  In modern php versions, this is ambiguous: `$ff_processor->rows[$r]`  it could be interpreted  as `{$ff_processor->rows}[$r]` or `$ff_processor->{rows[$r]}` -- I think you mean the former, so try `{$ff_processor->rows}[$r]`.  I would refactor this code to completely remove `ff_setSelectList1` and `ff_setSelectList2`.

Comment: `, $glue = 'AND'` has been succesfuly removed in both .php files, thank you. Now, `{$ff_processor->rows}[$r]` produces a syntax error so I gave up with it for the moment as it seems that even so it works. It seems that since Field3 loads requested data from the database, Field4 does not. So to my estimate the problem lies on the 3-4.php file (although it is almost identical to the 1-2.php file that works fine). Also, the Actionscript of Field3 is almost identical to the one in Field1 which works fine (only elements change), I think that the problem is within the 3-4.php file, but where?

Comment: Just an observation: if `$db2->quoteName('x.parent').' = '. $db2->quoteName('y.id')` is already in the LEFT JOIN and you want filter out rows that don't have `$db2->quoteName('x.parent').' = '. $db2->quoteName('y.id')`, then you should omit that filter from the `andWhere()` and instead use an `INNER JOIN`, right?

Comment: This looks like a typo: `JRequest::getVar(field3)`  ...see how you didn't quote the string?  I would expect to hear php barking at me for such a thing.  Do you have your error reporting turned all the way up?

Comment: Instead of using `JRequest::getVar(field3)` I have already tried `$jinput2 = JFactory::getVarApplication()->input; $judgePick2 = $jinput2->get('field3');` but it doesn't seem to work in breezing forms. Error reporting is set to Development. Concerning your observation above, the question to me is why the query works in 1-2.php as is? The whole procedure is identical. I will try to connect field3 and field4 using Actionscript of field1 and 1-2.php, to see if that works. Normaly it should. By the way, I have even removed and recreated field3 and field4! (desperate!)

Comment: Sorry I don't have BreezingForms to play with so I would be very annoying in asking for debugging details throughout the flow of the script to isolate where the breakage is.  I don't like the coding style, frankly.  I don't know if `field3` is a constant that wasn't properly uppercased.  I dont know if the fault is in the client-side or seever-side scripting.

Comment: Ok, I think we made a progress to this. By using SELECT tableA in both sets (Field 1 and 2) and (Field 3 and 4) it worked fine! Therefore I think I can conclude that the coding seems to be fine and the issue relies on tableB. I will search more to find out what is wrong with it (since it is identical to tableA) or maybe recreate it.

Comment: In phpMyAdmin when I click on tableB the following message appears "Warning: a form on this page has more than 2000 fields. On submission, some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's max_input_vars configuration". I have checked the PHP setting and it is set to 10000...

Comment: Concerning `JRequest::getVar(field3)` it was quoted like `JRequest::getVar('field3')`, just missed it in my comment.

Comment: Good work @Gal  Please [edit] your question as you continue to make progress.  When you edit your question, it gets bumped to the top of the "active questions" list which may attract new volunteers to chime in.  If you manage to resolve your own question, please resolve this page by self-answering with the intent to educate researchers with a similar problem -- this is in the best interest of JSE and Joomla.  (I will want to trim away any unnecessary comments under this question after it is resolved so that the page is not too long.)

Comment: Of course @mickmackusa

Comment: I have recreated the table and entered manualy a couple of values and it works fine but when I import a .csv with 1.197 rows it doesn't work.

Comment: This indicates that perhaps the csv data is corrupted?  Do you have values in that csv containing single quotes, double quotes, multibyte characters?  Maybe it is the script that is doing the importing is flawed -- I don't know. Unfortunately it is not very fun scrutinising 1200 rows of csv data.  If you are reviewing the data as a spreadsheet, you may actually need to review it as a raw csv file to spot any nasty anomalies.  If you have values that contain double quotes, per say, then you should escape them and wrap the whole value in double quotes.  Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, Greek letters are unicode/multibyte.  You may want to pay careful attention that your database is properly configured to handle your charset and that your whole application is "UTF-8 all the way through" <-- if you want to Google that.

Comment: @mickmackusa The problem is solved after all! It was caused by a row in the column `name` of the table. The row was starting with a space (no character). It was something like ` greekname182` rather than `greekname182` . I really don't understand why but this solved the issue. Thank you very much for your effort and your suggestions, much appreciated!

Comment: Okay, then I must do some housekeeping.  This page is Off-topic: Typo.  I am happy to see that you have resolved your issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by a typographical error.

Comment: Agreed, it should be closed. Thanks again.