# Mysqli query with regex to Joomla php syntax

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, regex

```
// CODE1 (Mysql (MariaDB 10.8.3) query):

SELECT s.`p_p`, COUNT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.`xml`, '[0-9]+'))
 FROM `#__s` AS s, `#__p` AS x, `#__v` AS r
 WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.`xml`, '[0-9]+') = [user_id] AND s.`user_id` = r.`user` AND x.`id` = s.`p_p`
 GROUP BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.`xml`, '[0-9]+'), s.`p_p`
 ORDER BY FIELD(x.`id`, 44, 14, 11, 10, 18, 4)

// Note1: works fine
```

```
// CODE2 (phpMyAdmin (5.2.0) query convertion to PHP (7.4.30)):
$query = "SELECT s.`p_p`, COUNT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.`xml`, \'[0-9]+\'))
 FROM `#__s` AS s, `#__p` AS x, `#__v` AS r
 WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.`xml`, \'[0-9]+\') = [user_id] AND s.`user_id` = r.`user` AND x.`id` = s.`p_p`
 GROUP BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.`xml`, \'[0-9]+\'), s.`p_p`
 ORDER BY FIELD(x.`id`, 44, 14, 11, 10, 18, 4);"; 
 
// Note2: Having phpMyAdmin to convert CODE1 to php it gives CODE2. Only \ was added and made it not to work. Taking \ out, works just fine as it is exactly the same as CODE1 which also works.
```

```
// CODE3 (PHP (7.4.30) query in Joomla (3.10.11) syntax):
$query = $db
    ->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->quoteName('s.p_p'), $db->quoteName('COUNT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.`xml`, \'[0-9]+\'))'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__s', 's'), $db->quoteName('#__p', 'x'), $db->quoteName('#__v', 'r'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('(REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.`xml`, \'[0-9]+\'))') .' = [user_id]' AND $db->quoteName('s.user_id') .' = '. $db->quoteName('r.user') AND $db->quoteName('x.id') .' = '. $db->quoteName('s.p_p'))
    ->group($db->quoteName('(REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.`xml`, \'[0-9]+\'))'), $db->quoteName('s.p_p'));
    
// Note3: In an effort to convert CODE1 to Joomla syntax, I can't make it work (even without the \). Using try/catch throws an error in line ->group. I also need to add the ORDER BY FIELD(x.`id`, 44, 14, 11, 10, 18, 4) but I don't know how.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quoteName()` is something that you call when you are quote-wrapping identifiers.  `(REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.xml, \'[0-9]+\'))` is not a table name or column name so it makes no sense to try to wrap it in quotes as an identifier.

In fact, I don't see any reason to use ANY of those `quoteName()` method calls in your script.  It only bloats the syntax, and makes your code harder to "eyeball".  There isn't any security/stability improvement for calling `quoteName()` either.

[`JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($query->dump(), 'notice');`](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/27909/12352) can prove very helpful as a sanity check when queries are failing.

Ultimately, I'm saying, remove all of those `quoteName()` calls and those manually written backticks, then try your query again.

P.S. Since `where()`'s default glue is `AND`, I'd personally prefer to feed it an array of rules:

```
->where([
    "REGEXP_SUBSTR(r.xml, '[0-9]+') = [user_id]",
    "s.user_id = r.user",
    "x.id = s.p_p"
])
```

Err, wait.  I don't like old-skool comma joins -- they also trick the developer eye.  I recommend using explicit INNER JOINs with ON clauses for clarity.  This means you will only have one rule in your WHERE clause (so no array is needed).

Comment: Concerning `quoteName()` I can now understand, thanks. `JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($query->dump(), 'notice'); ` doesn't produce any error since it doesn't seem to be a syntax error? I had also checked with [link](https://phpcodechecker.com) but no warnings appeared. Concerning "...manually written backticks...", they were added by phpMyAdmin together with \ in regex when it converted the query to PHP. I will remove them following what you said. Finally, haven't figured out yet how to use "Order by field" in Joomla syntax.

Comment: I don't mean the backslashes " \ ", I mean the backticks " ` ".  When you want backticks, use `quoteName()` instead. `$query->dump()` isn't meant to show errors, just show you what the rendered SQL looks like.  Then you can more easily review the query and/or paste it in your phpMyAdmin.  Are the values in the `FIELD()` function static/known or are they dynamic?

Comment: CODE2 works fine although not in Joomla syntax. Further on I use `loadObjectList` and then `if(isset` to get what I need from the array. Changing everything not the best option for me. I defintely do more than one things wrong when converting it to Joomla syntax. Answering your question, each of the value represents a specific subscription plan, so the plan values do not change. A user though `[user_id]` might have some none or or all of them and that is why I use `if(isset`